# How to control an Entry's Placeholder Text Color When Disabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 2 entries. Either can be used as input and the other as output for a calculation. When one gets a value entered into it, the other is disabled so a user can't enter values. My problem is that when the entry is disabled, both the placeholder text and the text go dark grey. This is despite having set the text and placeholder colors for the disabled state. I have tried all sorts of methods for setting the color with no luck. It is always overridden. I have no problem changing the color of the background when the entry is disabled, but the text will not change.

I have tried using a custom Entry control and setting the property when the IsEnabled property is changed. Also I have tried applying a Style that includes Triggers and I have tried setting the Triggers in the XAML, nothing is working.

Any suggestions?

```
<Entry
     HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
     Keyboard="Numeric"
     Placeholder="0"
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     IsEnabled="{Binding MinuteEnabled}"
     Text="{Binding MinuteString, Mode=TwoWay}">


     <Entry.Triggers>
         <Trigger TargetType="Entry"
             Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />

        </Trigger>
    </Entry.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is hard to archive, but a posible solution is having some entra hidden Labels binding to your outputs.

Here some sample code, you can archive to make it with view models.

XAML

```
<Label x:Name="Output1"
       TextColor="Green"
       BackgroundColor="Yellow"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       FontSize="Medium"
       HeightRequest="35"
       IsVisible="False" />
<Entry x:Name="entry1"
       Keyboard="Numeric"
       Placeholder="0"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
<Entry x:Name="entry2"
       Keyboard="Numeric"
       Placeholder="0"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
<Label x:Name="Output2"
       TextColor="Green"
       BackgroundColor="Yellow"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       FontSize="Medium"
       HeightRequest="35"
       IsVisible="False" />
```

And code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        entry1.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            // All your logic here or do it on view model
            entry2.IsVisible = false;
            Output2.IsVisible = true;
            Output2.Text = entry1.Text;
        };

        entry2.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            // All your logic here or do it on view model
            entry1.IsVisible = false;
            Output1.IsVisible = true;
            Output1.Text = entry2.Text;
        };
    }
}
```

And you can add it a clear button to restore both entries and labels.

Comment: Darn, I was afraid that this was a forms limitation.Thanks.

Comment: @Sevren Did your custom render doesn't work? how do you implement it?